# Porting from cygwin to win32 native program

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cygwin, winsock

I am porting the [Enhanced CTorrent](http://www.rahul.net/dholmes/ctorrent/) to Windows. But I'd like use Visual Studio to compile source code and get rid of cygwin.dll.

I found directives to conditionally use winsock header. But at moment I only can compile the source code by cygwin. I am wondering is the WINDOWS in code below same as _WIN32 in Visual Studio? And can cygwin directly use Win32 API as well?

```
#ifdef WINDOWS
#include <Winsock2.h>
#else
```

Comment: Winsock is, as the name suggest, Windows stuff. So I'd say yes and just try it.

Answer (score 2):

if you still want to keep this working under cygwin while you convert the source, you can use something like:

```
#if defined(WINDOWS) || defined(_WIN32)
#include <Winsock2.h>
#else
```

and for using Win32 API on cygwin, [see the FAQ](http://cygwin.com/faq/faq.programming.html#faq.programming.win32-api).